# Enabling and diasbling button if statement xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am looking to enable and disable a UIButton in XCode 7 using objective C. This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)startCount:(UIButton*)sender
{ 
    countInt = 0;
    self.Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countInt];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    if (countInt > 0){
        sender.enabled = false;    
    } else {
        sender.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Any idea as to why when I run this, the button doesn't enable and disable when desired?

Comment: `countInt = 0;` line executes always

Comment: @WarifAkhandRishi I have this also in the code `-(void)countTimer {
    
    countInt += 1;
    self.Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countInt];
    
    
}`

Comment: I suggest `NSLog` the `countInt`. if `countInt` is getter than 0 button should be disabled

Comment: still countInt is always 0 when the if statement is evaluated.

Comment: why r u using timer countTimer?

Comment: what do you mean when desired? Mention your conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable the button when `countInt` is greater then 0, you have to move the code that does it to `countTimer` function.

```
-(void)countTimer { 
  if (countInt > 0){
    myButton.enabled = false;

  } else {
    myButton.enabled = true;
  }

  countInt += 1;
  self.Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", countInt];
}
```

But there's other ways to do this more efficiently.

Comment: Sorry. The condiotional expression was in the wrong place.

Comment: For newer Devs, this still works (Xcode 11.2.1 at least). One crucial thing I learned that may not be obvious. You have to add an Outlet for the button (in addition to the action/segue wish to have take place).